# jQuery $.get returns empty, NOT cross-domain

Tags: jquery

Probably the simplest usage of $.ajax and $.get and yet it fails.

I'm pulling in HTML from a URL on the same domain:

```
$.get("/url", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The problem here is that the function returns empty, without an error, without a "cross-domain" alert. But if I check the network logs, the request was completed successfully and a full string of HTML was returned.

So what could possibly junk jQuery? Does it jam if the response had a format it didn't like?

Comment: You mean `data` is undefined, right? The actual `$.get` method always returns `undefined`.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: it returns jqXHR actually

Comment: Actually the console part doesn't even fire. Looks like a jQuery error but unfortunately it doesn't tell me anything in the inspector.

Comment: @DeLongey: and what about network in firebug?

Comment: firebug says the request was successful, too. it looks like jQuery doesn't like the response for some reason

Comment: @DeLongey: create small static html that reproduces the issue

Comment: @zerkms - Right-O. I was just making sure this wasn't another "The 'A' Stands For Asynchronous" question. Been seeing a lot of those, it seems.

Comment: Does jQuery expect a $.get response to be formatted in a certain way? like how $.getJSON expects valid JSON? I'll see if I can get a static page up

Comment: @DeLongey What is the exact error you get in the browser console?

Comment: @OscarJara I found a solution. But re: your question the point was that there were *no* errors :)

Comment: @DeLongey But what did console.log(data) returns? undefined, null, an XHR object?

Comment: @OscarJara it wasn't logging at all (console was mint). i think `$.get` has a `try{} catch{}` that silences the errors.

Comment: @DeLongey Uhm, it is supposed to get something. Check my comment in your alternative solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why it made the difference, but using this:

```
$('#resource-html').load(url);
```

Got it working. Must be related to how jQuery handles the data.

### Update

I can confirm the cause of the problem. There was a rogue header injected into the response, so the content-type was coming back as `application/json` although it was regular text. So most likely jQuery was trying to parse JSON that was actually HTML or just ignoring it altogether.

Lesson learned: check your response headers.

Comment: For the purpose of getting the HTML code to load it maybe into div, it is supposed to work perfect but what happens if you want to just get a piece of text of the HTML code you are trying to load? You won't be able to do it through this method :-)

Comment: Yea unfortunately I'm aware of that. I'm actually using it to pull in Munin graphs http://munin-monitoring.org/ of server resources. But what I'm going to do is change the Munin templates so they just output JSON and then use the graph URLs to build the page. :)

Comment: Did that page has RSS feeds for what you need maybe? there is another way to get data in that way. Yes, will be good to use JSON and try JSON methods for parsing.

Comment: Seems like Munin graphs are the only output. I think beyond that you're paying enterprise support LOL. Agreed RSS would be nice.

Comment: lol, could you please share the exact link you want to do the $get? I will test some things later and let you know.

Comment: @OscarJara can't it's under HTTP auth :) but see my updated answer I found the cause. I'm also going to open source my JSON Munin templates (if you use resource monitoring at all) in case you're interested